# wp e-commerce country list at checkout

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, e-commerce

Ok I have a store at http://sergedenimes.com/products-page/

It uses the wp e-commerce plugin on wordpress. I have modified the theme files to get the appearance and layout I want but the other day another site user took the liberty of updating the plugin without backing up the files thus overwriting my changes.

(I know this shouldn't have happened and I should have the theme files in a different directory but that's a different issue)

Anyways, luckily I managed to restore almost all of the theme files to my ones and the store is back to how it was, except for one thing: on the checkout page there is a dropdown where the user selects their country so the store can calculate delivery costs. This dropdown now has no countries listed in it. I checked the checkout theme file and it has the `<?php echo wpsc_shipping_country_list();?>` tag in the correct place.

Any ideas why the country list is not populated with selections any more? How can I fix?

(in order to see for yourself you'll need to add at least one product to cart and go to the checkout)

Thanks

Edit in answer to Marty's points:

- The total price will always include shipping - it is a physical item and shipping is added. The default shipping country is UK which is why it adds on £3.60
- Not sure about the zipcode box. can you provide a screenshot? For me it says nothing of providing a zip code - it says "Please choose a country below to calculate your delivery costs" (as it should) then there is a dropdown with no options in it to select. (which is my problem). I can't see a textfield here and there shouldn't be one.
- Despite perhaps being on a Canadian server the site and company is UK-based and thus the currency reflects this
- Thanks for the link although it doesn't seem to contain the solution. Tried deactivating/reactivating and now the checkout link in the cart widget goes to the wrong page.

(OK fixed the cart widget link issue but the country dropdown is still broken)

Another Edit:
Here is a pastebin of my entire checkout page template file: http://pastebin.com/aGxqsTVt

**Update**:
So I've tried checking the queries in the core files and adding the wp_ prefix to the table names with no luck.
Still really struggling with this and it seems like the update has messed up a lot of things, including that the store is now showing products that are saved as drafts.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

OK so I'm adding a php and mysql tag to this as that's where I believe the problem lies.

Here is the function that I believe is supposed to produce the country list:

```
function wpsc_shipping_country_list( $shippingdetails = false ) {
global $wpdb, $wpsc_shipping_modules, $wpsc_country_data;
$js = '';
$output = '';
if ( !$shippingdetails ) {
    $output = "<input type='hidden' name='wpsc_ajax_actions' value='update_location' />";
    $js = "  onchange='submit_change_country();'";
}
$selected_country = (string) wpsc_get_customer_meta( 'shipping_country' );
$selected_region  = (string) wpsc_get_customer_meta( 'shipping_region'  );

if ( empty( $selected_country ) )
    $selected_country = esc_attr( get_option( 'base_country' ) );

if ( empty( $selected_region ) )
    $selected_region = esc_attr( get_option( 'base_region' ) );

if ( empty( $wpsc_country_data ) )
    $country_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `" . WP_WPSC_CURRENCY_LIST . "` WHERE `visible`= '1' ORDER BY `country` ASC", ARRAY_A );
else
    $country_data = $wpsc_country_data;

$acceptable_countries = wpsc_get_acceptable_countries();

$output .= wpsc_get_country_dropdown( array(
    'name'                  => 'country',
    'id'                    => 'current_country',
    'additional_attributes' => $js,
    'acceptable_ids'        => $acceptable_countries,
    'selected'              => $selected_country,
    'placeholder'           => '',
) );

$output .= wpsc_shipping_region_list( $selected_country, $selected_region, $shippingdetails );

if ( isset( $_POST['wpsc_update_location'] ) && $_POST['wpsc_update_location'] == 'true' ) {
    wpsc_update_customer_meta( 'update_location', true );
} else {
    wpsc_delete_customer_meta( 'update_location' );
}

$zipvalue = (string) wpsc_get_customer_meta( 'shipping_zip' );
if ( ! empty( $_POST['zipcode'] ) )
    $zipvalue = $_POST['zipcode'];

$zip_code_text = __( 'Your Zipcode', 'wpsc' );

if ( ( $zipvalue != '' ) && ( $zipvalue != $zip_code_text ) ) {
    $color = '#000';
    wpsc_update_customer_meta( 'shipping_zip', $zipvalue );
} else {
    $zipvalue = $zip_code_text;
    $color = '#999';
}

$uses_zipcode = false;
$custom_shipping = get_option( 'custom_shipping_options' );
foreach ( (array)$custom_shipping as $shipping ) {
    if ( isset( $wpsc_shipping_modules[$shipping]->needs_zipcode ) && $wpsc_shipping_modules[$shipping]->needs_zipcode == true ) {
        $uses_zipcode = true;
    }
}

if ( $uses_zipcode ) {
    $output .= " <input type='text' style='color:" . $color . ";' onclick='if (this.value==\"" . esc_js( $zip_code_text ) . "\") {this.value=\"\";this.style.color=\"#000\";}' onblur='if (this.value==\"\") {this.style.color=\"#999\"; this.value=\"" . esc_js( $zip_code_text ) . "\"; }' value='" . esc_attr( $zipvalue ) . "' size='10' name='zipcode' id='zipcode'>";
}
return $output;
}
```

Comment: weird on the checkout page my order was 49(Serge DeNimes Block (Black) (M)) but total price was 52.60, even with no shipping? Also were your country list is, it says this: Please provide a Zipcode and click Calculate in order to continue. even though its not a text field for a zipcode (also, its a Canadian hosted site) why is prices in GBP? 
just wondering!

on topic: possible cause here!
http://getshopped.org/forums/topic/base-countryregion-list-is-empty/

Comment: thanks for the response - my points above

Answer (score 0):

ok looking at the most recent version of the checkout.class.php file there dosnt seem to be any use of the $wpdb->prefix do you use a prefix on your database tables? not just wp_ ?

```
$country_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `" . WPSC_TABLE_CURRENCY_LIST . "` WHERE `visible`= '1' ORDER BY `country` ASC", ARRAY_A );
```

should be something like?

```
$country_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `" . $wpdb->prefix.WPSC_TABLE_CURRENCY_LIST . "` WHERE `visible`= '1' ORDER BY `country` ASC", ARRAY_A );
```

check your database structure in phpmyadmin to see if the table names match?

[update] yea just read through the install files and they use the prefix, 
but still check to make sure you still have data in those tables?

Comment: I don't use any unusual prefixes - just the default wp_. Trying to check the db but can't seem to access cpanel as yet. Getting in touch with hosts now.

Comment: OK so checked my phpmyadmin: the table is called "wp_wpsc_currency_list" and is populated with all the country data

Comment: The sql queries are like the first one you mentioned (without the prefix). I tried adding `$wpdb->prefix` to the wpsc_shipping_country_list function but no luck. It calls the wpsc_get_country_dropdown function but I don't know where it's located. This is ridiculous that they sent out an update with these problems in it.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue when i updated. I found the cause of the issue was the change over from U.K. to Great Britain. Make sure you use Great Britain instead of the old U.K. in the admin and your issue should be solved.

Frank.